# How do you set the data of a SVG image element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo's .exportSVG() to export a chart, and then I am building up a new SVG using that exported string. How do I create an SVG with the exported data? I have the following

```
var chartSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
```

but how do I set the data?

The exported string starts out like the following (cut it off because it's very long)

> data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0nMS4wJyA/Pjxzdmc

Comment: setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', your exported string);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setAttributeNS()` with the xlink namespace.

```
chartSvg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", yourDataUrl);
```